# Latin Modern Roman for TTF

Tags: fonts, latin-modern, truetype

I can not find **TTF** version of popular LaTeX font family: **Latin Modern Roman**. I have found only **OTF** version. Is there any restrictions about **TTF** implementation or I am bad in searching?

Comment: Why do you need a TTF version?

Comment: Because code that I write can not access OTF fonts

Comment: I see. No there isn’t, but you can use a proper font editor to do the conversion, as answered below.

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer, but a workaround:

If you already have the otf font you can use e.g. [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) to convert the files.
OTF is just an extended version of TTF, the method how glyphs are specified is the same, so the characters will stay the same.

Comment: I don't think so. OpenType has two flavors, one TrueType one PS. I believe LM is PS flavor OTF and thus a CFF font and the glyphs are described in cubic Bézier splines while TrueType fonts use quadratic Bézier splines. Converting are possible but I am so sure that they will be identical. In addition, CFF and TrueType have very different hinting mechanism.

Comment: I checked again, and you are right. OTF seems to be able to use cubic and quadratic splines, whereas TTF font only use quadratic splines. If the conversion algorithm is good it should not matter, the TTF font would just use (many) more control points than the OTF font.
Anyways, if the OP has to use a TTF font there is most likely no alternative, I doubt that one would go through the chores of designing the font twice, once for OTF and once for TTF...

Comment: LM does indeed use cubic outlines. So the conversion to TTF (quadratic curves) would not be exact, but would probably be good enough. As mentioned above, flawed conversion (or non-conversion) of the hinting info would probably do more harm than approximation in the outline geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I found the answer here: https://medium.com/@fulowa/latex-font-in-a-ggplot-9120caaa5250

*Edit*: The Font Squirrel website provides a TTF webfont version.

- Open webpage https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman
- Click "Webfont Kit", then check "TTF"
- Click "DOWNLOAD @FONT-FACE KIT", then you download a zip file containing TTF version fonts.

PS (from @muzimuzhiZ): I've not tested those TTF files yet.

[image]

Comment: Can you copy and paste the core part here because external links are subject to 404?